# in QTextEdit ，can't respond to mouse click events

Tags: qtextedit, qevent

I want to use mouseDoubleClickEvent,but it does not work
this is my code:
 `textEdit->setMouseTracking(true);`

who can help me ? thank you sorry,my English is so bed

Comment: I think it's better to include more code in your question. What have you done?